# React js: Show certain element from object in frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend

So i set up a database which is running and having 31 objects in it.

Now i connected the database to my frontend and log it there in the console, as you can see here:

[image]

Now lets say i want to display the text from the object with the id : 1 there. Which would be in this case "Source". It should be displayed under my h1 field which says "Show me Text from object with id 1".

How do i achieve this?

Here is my code:

Backend (index.js):

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors');

const db = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password:"mypassword",
  database:'myDatabase',
});


app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.get('/api/get', (req,res)=>{

    const sqlSelect = 'SELECT * FROM myDatabase.signaldb;'
    db.query(sqlSelect, (err,result)=> {
  
      res.send(result);
      if (err) console.log(err);
    })

})





app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("running on port 3001")
})
```

Frontend (App.js)

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";


const App = () => {

const [signalList, setsignalList] = useState([]);


useEffect(()=> {
  Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/get").then((response) => 
  {
    //log data 
    console.log("response data: ");
    console.log(response.data);
    setsignalList(response.data)
  })
});





  return (
      
    <div>
      <h1>Show me Text from object with id 1</h1>
      
    </div>

    );
}



export default App;
```

Comment: Your `useEffect` should have an empty dependency array: `useEffect(() => do something, []);` so that it only loads data on the first render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use forEach/map/filter to loop within the list of elements and when it finds the one that matches the id that you are looking for, render it.

**Filter solution:**

```
return (
  <div>
    <h1>{signalList.filter(obj => obj.id == yourId)[0].text}</h1>
  </div>
);
```

The filter is the easiest straight-on solution, but maybe if you want to do something with the other elements that you are not rendering because the ID isn't the one you are looking for, a map loop would be the solution.

**Map solution:**

```
return (
  <div>
    {signalList ? signalList.map(obj => obj.id == yourId ? <h1>{obj.text}</h1>) : DO SOMETHING ELSE}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The Map Solution is working but the filter solution doesnt work. Is it possible that you made a syntax error there by leaving out curly braces or something?

Comment: @Liebertosan I think there was an extra parenthesis. I've edit my response, now it should work correctly!

Comment: yes ist does thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use map function

```
const [signalList, setsignalList] = useState([]);


useEffect(()=> {
  Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/get").then((response) => 
  {
    //log data 
    console.log("response data: ");
    console.log(response.data);
    setsignalList(response.data)
  })
//please add empty array if you want to just execute this function once on mount
},[]);





  return (
      
    <div>
      <h1>{ signalList.map((e,i)=> e.id==1 ? e.text : '' }</h1>
      
    </div>

    );
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `map` in your answer?

Comment: 1) They're not pretty much the same thing. One mutates the array, the other returns a _new_ array. 2) Your answer says _"use the `map` function"_ but you don't use it in your answer.

Comment: @Andy good to know!  forEach actually returns undefined.

Comment: Thank you very much. But this only shows the id of the object i want it does not return the text like i want it to

Comment: You need more clarity on how to access the objects and work on your logic. ive made changes if solves your problem mark the answer as answered

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your IDs are distinct you can do like this. `yourId` is what you want to search for.

```
 return (
    <div>
      <h1>(signalList.filter(obj => obj.id == yourId))[0].text)</h1>
    </div>
    );
```

Comment: Is this the correct syntax? Because when i try to copy it like this he shows me a syntax error

Comment: I by mistake left the closing curly braces. Essentially, I just wanted to show the JSX being returned. Where exactly are you getting Syntax Error?

Comment: when i add the curly brackets at the end it says that there is still a bracket missing.